# Can't login to my own website

Tags: login

I've had a WordPress site since March 2016 but a few years ago I lost the ability to log into my own website. I'm using the twentysixteen theme so there's a little panel at the bottom of the screen that I can click on and log in.

When I do this, the log in window appears, I put my info into the fields and then sign in but get kicked right back to my website and logged out. If I add "wp-login.php" at the end of it, then it sends me to wp-admin but if I now go to my website I'm still logged out.

This is super annoying and I really want to try and fix it, so if anyone has any idea *what the heck* is going on, I'd really appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

It sounds as though you know your username and password, but if not you can always go into PHPMyAdmin (Or whatever Db tool your server uses) and navigate to the **users** table. In there you can see your users, and edit your details as required, including your password which you can simply overtype with new after encrypting it in **MD5** format.

If this is trying to log in and kicking you straight back to the login page it may be worth looking in your server root for a file named `error_log`, this will help you identify any errors, or you can edit `wp-config.php` in the site's root setting `wp_debug` to **true** near the end of the page. Doing this should stop the page from just redirecting you without notification and give a print out of the error, if there are, any at the top of the page.

This may not help, we could probably do with some more details from you before the community can help further. Depending on your hosting environment, it could be that your PHP version is out of date and needs updating.

Hope this helps. Ben.

Answer (score -1):

I just had to click the "not you?" button then log in as myself and it works.